# Sort order of relatives imports?

Tags: python, python-import, pep

What is the right or PEP way to sort **relative imports** in python?

```
core/
    __init__.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        form_tests/
             __init__.py
            test_xpto.py
        login.py
```

If I am working with `test_xpto.py` and would like to import other files, what is the correct way:

```
from core.models import Person
from ..login import DefaultLogin
from ...forms import CustomerForm
```

or

```
from ...forms import CustomerForm
from ..login import DefaultLogin
from core.models import Person
```

or is not any of them?

Comment: The official guidelines are here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports. Anything beyond those is up to you and your team to decide which you prefer.

Comment: See [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

Comment: Following the link jonsharpe gave, the bullet point after sorting import says: „Absolute imports are recommended, […]“, so just don't use relative imports and follow the guidelines in the first two bullet points.  Then there is not much to decide any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some answers to this question. According to with PEP 328 [1], has Guido pronounced saying that "relative imports will use leading dots. A single leading dot indicates a relative import, starting with the current package. Two or more leading dots give a relative import to the parent(s) of the current package, one level per dot after the first" [2]. Here's a sample package layout:

```
from .moduleY import spam
from .moduleY import spam as ham
from . import moduleY
from ..subpackage1 import moduleY
from ..subpackage2.moduleZ import eggs
from ..moduleA import foo
from ...package import bar
from ...sys import path
```

Another good idea is isort (a Python utility / library to sort imports alphabetically, and automatically separated into sections) [3], which to sort the imports  has followed an other pattern, which is used by big projects like Django [4]:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import sys

from my_lib import Object, Object2, Object3
from third_party import (lib1, lib2, lib3, lib4, lib5, lib6, lib7, lib8, lib9,
                         lib10, lib11, lib12, lib13, lib14, lib15)

from . import moduleY
from ...sys import path
from ..subpackage1 import moduleY
from ..subpackage2.moduleZ import eggs
from .moduleY import spam as ham
```

[1] https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision

[2] https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-March/043739.html

[3] https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort

[4] https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort/wiki/Projects-Using-isort